# Limpar campo de form, caso autocomplete seja null

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

Estou usando o código para autocomplete abaixo. Eu digito as iniciais de uma fruta e meu select retorna com os nomes das frutas que coincidam com essas iniciais. Selecionando uma delas, eu pego o id e jogo em outro campo. Até o momento funciona o problema é que eu queria que caso não fosse encontrado nada, limpasse o campo com id.

***Exemplo:***

Abro o formulário e preencho "ma" vai aparecer mamão e se eu selecionar mamão o cod 1 vai para o campo `idFruta` apago e digito "li" aparece limão e o `idFruta` é preenchido com 2 isso tudo tá funcionando.

Agora se digito "zz" não aparece nada, apenas a mensagem "fruta não encontrada" mas meu campo `idFruta` permanece com o `id` da fruta selecionada anteriormente. Eu queria então que ao selecionar "Fruta inexistente" limpasse o meu campo `idFruta`.

#### Tem como fazer isso?

```js
jQuery.fn.autoCompleteEditora = function (idCod, idFocus, formAddFruta) {
    $(this).autocomplete({
        appendTo: formAddFruta,
        source: function (request, response) {
            $("#loadingFruta").show();
            $.ajax({
                url: '../fruta/frutas.json',
                type: "GET",
                dataType: "json",
                contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8",
                data: {
                    q: request.term
                },
                success: function (data) {
                    if (!data.length) {
                        var result = [
                            {
                                label: 'Fruta inexistente' ,
                                value: response.term
                            }
                        ];
                        response(result);
                    } else {
                        response($.map(data, function (item) {
                            return {
                                label: item.nome,
                                id: item.cod,
                                abbrev: item
                            };
                        }));
                        $("#loadingFruta").hide();
                    }
                }
            });
        },
        minLength: 2,
        focus: function (event, ui) {
            $(this).val(ui.item.label);
            return false;
        },
        select: function (event, ui) {
            cod = ui.item.abbrev.cod;
            idCod.val(cod);
            (idFocus !== null) ? idFocus.focus() : idCod.focus();

        }
    });
    $["ui"]["autocomplete"].prototype["_renderItem"] = function (ul, item) {
        return $("<li></li>")
                .data("item.autocomplete", item)
                .append($("<a></a>").html(item.label))
                .appendTo(ul);
    };
};
```

Comment: Quando dizes "fruta não encontrada" o que aparece é "Fruta inexistente"? É nessa parte que vês se existe ou não certo?

Comment: Isso mesmo. Vou corrigir o texto.

Comment: Tabém ajudava se colocasses aqui o html para ver os elementos a que te referes etc... Podes colocar aqui se quiseres: https://jsfiddle.net/ , com o funcionanmento que tem até agora

Comment: Adiciona a função `response` aqui também.

Comment: Tem certeza que foi você que escreveu esse código, pois pra mim a solução é tão óbvia que não consigo acreditar que alguém que desenvolveu toda essa lógica, não sabe onde restar o valor do campo.... Mas vai uma pista.  No bloco de código onde você adiciona "Fruta inexistente"... adicione algo desse tipo "idCod.val('');" Como não sei se idCod é global, nem o id do input, não posso postar um código como resposta.

Comment: @mauhumor Não fui eu que fiz. Por essa razão estou pedindo ajuda.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode resetar o campo dentro do if que verifica se a resposta da requisição ajax não possui conteúdo. Incluído a seguinte linha:

```
 idCod.val('');
```

Estou supondo que `idCod` é global, já que foi utilizado em outro evento, e suponho também que o código postado está funcionado. Deve ficar assim:

```
  ...
  if (!data.length) {
      var result = [
         {
          label: 'Fruta inexistente' ,
          value: response.term
         }
      ];
      idCod.val('');    //Incluir esta linha
      response(result);
   } else {
   ...
```

Update: `idCod` está dentro do escopo. Não tinha reparado inicialmente. Então é dessa forma mesmo.

Comment: Funcionou como eu precisava. Muito obrigada. Boas Festas.